# IOS Swift - Camera view overlay shouldn't cover status bar

Tags: swift, camera, overlay

[image]I am learning Swift - making progress. My application should scan a barcode. I am trying to show the camera in the middle of the screen between two strips of spaces above and below the UIview. There is a button at bottom strip of space to save the barcode number. My issue is, I need to show the status bar at the top of the screen with signal strength, time, battery etc., when user is scanning, but it is covered by the UI view when it open camera. I have reviewed other posts and incorporated the suggestions, but the issue persists. Any help is appreciated.

I have uploaded image showing the covered status bar.

Here is my code:

---

```
class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var selectScan1: UIButton!

var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   // view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.ean8, .ean13, .pdf417]
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.frame
    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
    // **** note: select click to bounds check box in storyboard

    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

---

[image: I]

[image]

Comment: What is `cameraView` anchored to? `Superview`?

Comment: Yes, I have attched a screenshot of the tree. I have constraint: "Camera view.top = safe area.top +44"

Comment: Have you tried removing the +44 constant from the constraint, or is this a quick fix of you?

Comment: No, that constraint has been there. I tried removing it now; and also setting it to 0. No changes

Comment: You can set a `backgroundColor` for `cameraView` to see whether its the `cameraView` or the preview layer misbehaving. If the `previewLayer` is misbehaving you can set its frame in `didLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Setting the CameraView background to green clearly shows that it is not the issue (see picture attached). Could you help me with an example for setting frames for preViewLayer? I believe it should be an override to didLayoutSubviews

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/view-controller-lifecycle/ for an example how to use it. Where is the status bar here in the picture?

Comment: That is my issue. I expected status bar to be at the top of the white strip above green area, I am not getting it

Comment: Hm thats weird. Did you try `didLayoutSubviews` to set the frame of previewLayer on every layout change? Otherwise its possibly just not filling all green since the camera has a certain aspect ratio. You can also try to comment out the previewLayer part to see if its a problem with that or if its a general issue.

Comment: Found out this issue. override prefersStatusBarHidden was set to true. This was commented out. Thanks for your time and help